# Error while build boost release

Tags: debugging, boost, release

I have error while building the release:

> 1>d:\work\boost\boost/asio/detail/socket_types.hpp(38): fatal error
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or
>   directory

But when build the Debug everything is fine.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

First , check that you have the Windows SDK installed

[Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ff851942.aspx)

Then go to Project property page and in configuration properties , General
select **"Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)"** for **Platform Toolset**

I had the same problem and fixed by this way